# Multiple onLocationChanged android google map?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-maps-utils

Can I use in `onConnected` from multiple `onLocationChanged`? for example first `onLocationChanged`for update location user and second `onLocationChanged` for other works :

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        LocationListener mListenerone = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            }
        };

        LocationRequest requestone = LocationRequest.create();
        requestone.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        requestone.setInterval(100);
        requestone.setFastestInterval(100);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, requestone, mListenerone);

        LocationListener mListenertwo = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            }
        };
        LocationRequest requesttwo = LocationRequest.create();
        requesttwo.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        requesttwo.setInterval(10000);
        requesttwo.setFastestInterval(1000);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, requesttwo, mListenertwo);
    }
```

Comment: Why you need to different  onConnected ?

Comment: @M D .In first onLocationChanged I need to track user each seconds and in second onLocationChanged I need to use from isLocationOnPath() every 100 meters.

Comment: @M D .Can I use from this way ?

Comment: Yes but it's useless becoz it's easy to handle and maintain single Object of   googleApiClient

Comment: @M D .Can you recommend a better solution ?

Comment: Get first location and save it some where and when you get next location get distance from save location to new location. If dis < 100 then use it.

Comment: @M D .Thanks a lot for your help but,is this way slow ?